# jQuery animate function callback bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code for sliding out a div:

```
var current = $('.s_text:visible');
current.animate({
  right: 1014,
  opacity:0,
},{queue: false, duration:2000}, function() {
  current.hide();
});
```

for some reason, the callback function doesn't work! but! If I remove the option `{queue:false, duration:2000}` and replace it with `,2000,function()....`  the callback function works.

```
current.animate({
      right: 1014,
      opacity:0,
    },2000, function() { // this one works...
      current.hide();
    });
```

Why is that?

Comment: You are using old jquery version Try to use this version <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
it is work fine for me

Comment: @jailalawat I'm using jquery 1.10.1

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: And I actually I was wrong about it (partially).

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah, [Rodik nailed it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20346363/157247).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the second parameter of the `.animate` method as an options object, you cannot send the callback as a third parameter.

In your case, you need to use the complete parameter of the options object.

```
var current = $('.s_text:visible');
current.animate({
  right: 1014,
  opacity:0,
},{queue: false, duration:2000, complete:function() {
  current.hide();
}});
```

the two optional parameter sets this method receives are:

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

or

```
.animate( properties, options )
```

but not both at once.

source: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Thanks! well explained!

Answer (score 1):

Animate:

```
.animate( properties, options )
```

Find reference here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
var current = $('.s_text:visible');
current.animate(
  {
    right    : 1014,
    opacity  :0
  },{
    queue   : false, 
    duration:2000,
    complete: function() {
         current.hide();
    }
 });
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please explain the problem and why your answer solves it.

Comment: Got it! thanks! Now I realise that how I had to do the callback function.

Comment: Better, even though your answer still doesn't contain an explanation. Keep this in mind for future answers.

Comment: @FelixKling Will do. Appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `options` (queue and duration) you cannot have a callback function like that; you should include the callback function in `options` (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options)):

```
var current = $('.s_text:visible');
current.animate({
    right: 1014,
    opacity:0
},{
    queue: false, 
    duration:2000,
    complete: function() {
        current.hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `.animate()` has only two declarations:

1. .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
2. .animate( properties, options )

none is for your useage, you could see more about `.animate()` here:http://api.jquery.com/animate/